# Why is map called more than one time?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-java2

I have the following code:

```
disposable = Single.fromCallable(() ->fetchData())
                .map(myObject::doUpdate)
                .subscribeOn(mySingleThreadScheduler)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnSuccess(consumer)
                .subscribe(myFunction, failConsumer);
```

What I see is that:
`fetchData()` and `myObject::doUpdate` are called by the same thread (based on the thread-name/thread-id) which I expected.
But the `myObject::doUpdate` us called more than 1 time and in the second time it is like it gets the input from before my `fetchData` run.
Why?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, but _complete_ example so we can reproduce it?

Comment: @marstran:It is very difficult as I am new in Java rx and have no idea how to extract the relevant things to make it a reproducable example. What I can say is that `fetchData` returns a `List<MyObject>` and `myObject::doUpdate` gets as input argument this list and returns an custom object that has that list as a member. I suspect that once `map` returns somehow the result is `map`pped again

Comment: @marstran: Actually I verified it is called as many times as the `size` of the input `list`

Comment: @Jim could you please provide the full code or at least the signature of the methods `fetchData()` and `myObject::doUpdate`?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the official documentation of ReactiveX `map` operator [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html) and the attached Marble diagram, you can see that map function is executed for every input

[image]

So you can't rely on it if you want to execute a function with all the elements available at once.

With `map` operator you can apply a transformation to each element which will be executed individually.

Comment: So how can I do then what I need if map is not the proper solution?

Comment: What are you tryng to achieve with the `onUpdate` function? When the function should be called?

Comment: "map function is executed for every input" - yes, but from the code Jim's posted there is only one input - the List<MyObject>.  The map function takes that one object, and returns another object.   There doesn't appear to be anything in the code that causes the List to be iterated through (ie, the code should never get to input marble "2", so how come output marble "20" is executed) - is that right @Jim ?

Comment: @racraman you are correct, we probably need to see the `fetchData` code